# Algorithm to animate a page flip in 3D?

Tags: animation, 3d, physics

I would like to make a realisticly looking page flip animation. It does not have to be a true physical model, as long as it looks convincing. Many shops have flash animations of their real-world brochures but I don't find them convincing. The page does not bend realistic, lighting is not correct, etc.

I will be happy with any links describing this problem, or code that implement it. I will be implementing this .net (using SlimDX or WPF).

Answer (score 2):

You can also try the links below:

- for source code have a look at cocos2d framework (see [CCPageTurn3D](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/api-ref/0.9.0-alpha/interface_c_c_page_turn3_d.html))
- for tutorials about 3D page flip see: [Adding 3rd dimension to the page flip effect on iPhone OS](http://nomtek.com/tips-for-developers/page-flip-3d/) or [W. Dana Nuon blog](http://wdnuon.blogspot.com/2010/05/implementing-ibooks-page-curling-using.html)